# how to bypass LDAP authentication after logged in with openid?

Tags: java, jboss, openid

I have a web application which uses LDAP for log in.

I'm using **Openid4Java** to let the users log in with an open id and this works great but when I want to do the redirect to my index.jsp page, **it redirects me back to the login page because I am not authenticated using LDAP**.

I have made a method to authenticate with a demo user with LDAP but the question is how to "tell" to the HttpResponse from open id that I am logged in with LDAP also?

This is the doGet method of the servlet which takes care of OpenId authentication. Also, you will notice that I do the LDAP auth. before doing the redirect (the single problem is that for openId I use my gmail account and for LDAP I use a demo account and I do not know how to handle the response...)

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("--------GET----------------");
    System.out.println("context: " + context);
    Identifier identifier = this.verifyResponse(req);
    System.out.println("identifier: " + identifier);
    if (identifier == null) {
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login_new.jsp")
                .forward(req, resp);
    } else {
        req.setAttribute("identifier", identifier.getIdentifier());
        final String applicationUrl = req.getRequestURL().toString();
        final String redirectTo = applicationUrl.substring(0,
                applicationUrl.indexOf("/servlet")) + "/" + "index.jsp";
        System.out.println("Login through open id succeded, redirect to: "
                + redirectTo);

        if (authenticateUserInJbossLDAP())
            resp.sendRedirect(redirectTo);
    }
}
```

Do you have any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the problem.

The key thing is to do the authentication to the web container from the servlet.  The new class called as "org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.login.**WebAuthentication**" can be used for this purpose.

So the final refined method will be:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.debug("------------------------");
        log.debug("context: " + context);
        Identifier identifier = this.verifyResponse(req);
        log.debug("identifier: " + identifier);
        // if openid login succeded redirect to home page using our demo account
        if (identifier != null) {
            WebAuthentication pwl = new WebAuthentication();
            pwl.login("guest", "guest");**
            resp.sendRedirect("/index.jsp");
        } else {
            System.out.println("login with openid failed");
        }
    }
```

The complete openid solution I've written down [here](http://crisdev.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/openid4java-login-example/).